# Error: Getter not found: 'location_on_outlined'

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

I am adding material icons available for Flutter. But when I added it shows error.
Here is my code:

```
Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, color: Colors.red, size: 20,),
```

Here is error:

```
Error: Getter not found: 'location_on_outlined'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Flutter material library does not have all the outline icons. Please refer the full list of available icons: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

However there is a package outline_material_icons that you may use. https://pub.dev/packages/outline_material_icons